# I want to use the data in the Controller in the View side javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, sms

this is my controller:

```
public ActionResult AjaxSmsSend(Sms smsInfo)
        {
            var sms = smsInfo.smsCode;
            var telephone = smsInfo.telephone;
            ViewBag.Code = sms;  
            return Json(sms); 
        }
```

In the View :

```
<button id="getDataBtn">Click me</button>
```

When I press this button :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#getDataBtn").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Home/AjaxSmsSend",
                data: sms,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json", 
        });
    });
</script>
```

I will use it to compare the sms data I received from the controller.

```
<p style="text-align: center;margin-top: 10%;">Enter your sms code</p>
<input type="text" id="pincode" maxlength="4">
```

This input is entered by the user. I have generated sms data in the controller itself.
I'm sure it's actually a very simple process. But since I've just started, I can't find what I'm looking for. I'd appreciate it if you could help me with that.

Comment: What's the question? It appears as though you're posting SMS data in an ajax request that you already have on server? What does the HTML have to do with anything? I think we're missing context that you have in your head :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's a good practice, normaly the comparison should in server side but you can Add this :

```
 success: function (response) {
                    if (response.smsCode)
                    {                     

                    }
                }
```

it will be like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#getDataBtn").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Home/AjaxSmsSend",
                data: sms,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.smsCode)
                    {                     

                    }
                }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then put your code inside this if :

```
if (response.smsCode)
                    {                     

                    }
```

That's all, I hope you find this helpful